# Is it possible to "mirror" a part of the contents of one layer onto another layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Intermediately experienced PS user here, but I'm always learning more and a recent project has me wondering if this is possible.

I have a large 3072x2048 texture file that is composed of six smaller 1024x1024 parts that are individually mapped to a 3D model:

[image: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/385255312686317578/488491990389096450/unknown.png]

I am curious if it is possible to set up a project file so that the 1024x1024 block in the upper right mirrors the content of the highlighted parts of the Left and Right layers above. I am currently doing this task manually but can't help but think there is an easier way to do what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with guides.

Selecting each part and making a layer via copy, after is possible to select the whole area and transform reflecting horizontally or/and vertically.

---

Following this .gif example:

- Activating the *blue layer* and selecting the *blue column area* >
  **Transform** > **Flip vertical**
- Activating the *yellow layer* and selecting the *yellow rectangle
  area* > **Transform** > **Flip vertical** and **Flip horizontal**

[image: transform]

Comment: Isn't this a manual way too? The smart object answer is the non-manual way. Update the main Smart Object and both instances of the Smart Object will follow.

Answer (score 3):

Use smart objects.

Make the left and right objects each as a smart object, and just copy them to the top right.

Bonus: Whenever you change a smart object, both instances will be updated.